# using expression and add all together in ng-class

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In angularJs ng-class uses [] to add a group of class to DOM element.

```
<div ng-class="['first','second']"></div>
```

And `{}` are use to Evaluate expression

```
<dive ng-class="{'first':true}"></dive>
```

Is there a way to use expression inside `[]`. I tried as follows but angular is throwing error.

```
<div ng-class="[{'first':true},'second']"></div>
```

How I can perform this inside ng-class.I want to add first class only if there is certain condition and second class will be always there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div ng-class="{ 'first second': true }"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="second" ng-class="{ 'first': true }"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use always use [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) attribute with Angular

```
<div class="second" ng-class="{'first':true}"></div>
```